# How to transpose an array of chars into a const char* string?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm designing a program that has a function that finds words from the input and then sends them to a different function to compare to a dictionary (array of `const char*` "strings").

I wanted to use `strncmp()` from `<string.h>` and, naturally, `strncmp()` expects both arguments to be `const char*`. Since I am parsing my input a char at a time, I am putting the words into an array.

How do I transpose an array of chars into a `const char*` "string"? I hate to admit it, but I really don't know how to do it. Searched around and couldn't find the answer.

The best  I have come up with is to use `memcpy()`... not sure if there are better ways?

**TL;DR** What are good ways to make an array of chars into a `const char*` "string"?

*For example*

```
char someArray[5] = "word"; /* assume generated char by char, null terminated */
const char* new_format = foo(someArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your array has a null terminator (a 0 byte) at the end, it can be used anywhere you need a pointer, since arrays decay into pointers to their first elements:

```
char someArray[5] = "word";
char *pointer = someArray;  // That's it!
strncmp(pointer, "something else", 5);

// Or, more simply:
char someArray[5] = "word";
strncmp(someArray, "something else", 5);
```

Comment: Easy button. Thanks--I was over thinking it!